# A Russian verb for finding support for one's idea or theory from a hardly-relevant source

Tags: выбор-слова

What verb would best describe in Russian the act of trying to find some support for one's idea or theory from some source that doesn't necessarrily  support or even focus on that idea?

For example,

> He was desperately trying to _________________ from  Confucius'
>   writings some support for his crazy ideas.

I am looking for a word that besides 'finding' ("выискивать") would also have a connotation of theorizing, which in the example above would be adding some personal interpretation or even development to Confucious' thoughts.

Comment: Since you're looking for a Russian word, could you please provide your placeholder phrase in Russian? Thanks!

Comment: "откопать"? "After years and years of digging in books, he finally managed to unearth a phrase that is definitely from Confucius and approves his ideas" - "После доглих лет, перерыв все книжные полки, он таки сумел откопать фразу точно от Конфуция и точно подтверждающую его идеи" (approximate translation).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not necessarily literary or flattering variants which come to mind are

> Он отчаянно старался/пытался **сфабриковать/сварганить/слепить** аргументы в пользу своих
>   безумных идей на основе произведений / опираясь на произведения / апеллируя к произведениям Конфуция
>
> Aргументацию в поддержку своих безумных идей он отчаянно пытался **(по)строить**, опираясь на произведения / апеллируя к произведениям Конфуция
>
> **В качестве базы** для своих безумных идей он отчаянно старался/пытался
>   **использовать** произведения Конфуция
>
> Он обращался к произведениям Конфуция, отчаянно пытаясь **построить/сформулировать на их базе хоть какое-то** обоснование / **некое подобие** обоснования своих безумных идей
>
> Отчаянно пытаясь **сфабриковать/сварганить/слепить хоть какие-то** аргументы в пользу своих безумных идей, он обращался/апеллировал к произведениям Конфуция
>
> Чтобы **хоть как-то** обосновать свои безумные идеи, он отчаянно пытался **притянуть за уши** труды Конфуция *(quite disparaging)*

Comment: I like *притянуть за уши*

Comment: @Quassnoi truth be told i liked it myself, which clicked with me at the last moment

Comment: @Quassnoi oh, was your comment a subtle hint about a typo?.. i totally missed it

Comment: @баянкупика: no it wasn't, it was a genuine appreciation.

Comment: @Quassnoi alright then

Answer (score 13):

You can use the informal word **приплести** to strongly express your disapproval and skepticism about it. It would emphasize the irrelevance of the source used.

> В поддержку своих безумных идей он упорно пытался *приплести* труды
>   Конфуция.

(Словарь Ожегова)
**Приплести**
Впутать во что н.; упомянуть зря (разг.)

Answer (score 8):

I would use *истолковать*:

> Он отчаянно пытался истолковать труды Конфуция в пользу поддержки своих безумных идей.

Answer (score 3):

I would propose the word **наскрести**, "to scrape", reminiscent of an English idiom "to scrape the bottom of the barrel":

> Он пытался **наскрести** у Конфуция хоть что-то в свою пользу

Answer (score 1):

> *подыскать, подобрать, обнаружить* хоть какое-то
>   обоснование своим безумным идеям
>   *выжать, извлечь* из трудов Конфуция
>   *нащупать* аргументы в поддержку

P.S.
Related to the comment from @Quassnoi, the phrase "в пользу поддержки" sounds incorrect to me.

Comment: it does sound off indeed, however *истолковать в пользу* is a set phrase.

Comment: @Quassnoi you may say either "в пользу" or "в поддержку", but "в пользу поддержки" is an erroneous repetition in this case: it might be used if "поддержка" meant an actual support of other action, e.g. "аргументы в пользу поддержки революции".

Comment: @IvanMilyakov: if we omit the rest of the phrase, are you suggesting using *истолковать в пользу идей* or *истолковать в поддержку идей*?

Comment: I'd go either with "в свою пользу" or "в поддержку [своих] идей"; "в пользу идей", while might be used in a conversation, sounds a bit illogical because it's people who may benefit from something, not ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Once can also use word `подвести`.

From [dictionary](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8&all=x):

> Подвести
>
> 6. кого-что подо что. Признать соответствующим чему-л., подогнать подо что-л., отнести к кругу каких-л. явлений.

So, it can be said that:

> Он отчаянно пытался подвести свои странные идеи под принципы,
> изложенные в работах Конфуция.

However, this word does carry meaning of trying to make one thing match something else. So, in the example above one is finding reasons why his ideas match concepts from Confucius' writings.